# Aws lambda code explanation

Tags: aws-lambda

Can anybody please explain the working of the below code.

```
"def lambda_handlerOut(event, context):
        if len(event) > 0:  
            success=1
            print("length of event outside for--"+str(len(event)))
            for record in event['Records']: 
                print("length of event--"+str(len(event)))
                bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']
                key=record['s3']['object']['key']
                print("Bucket--"+bucket)
                print("File that triggered this event--"+key)
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Eleena Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Lambda that receives S3 events - for example a [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) request that creates a new file.

The method is the standard Python function - take a look at the [Lambda Function Handler Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) for more details.

The structure of the event is defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) but basically there are some number of Records that are being iterated through with and, for each record, the bucket and key are being extracted and printed.

So, in more detail (comments above the line they reference):

```
# standard lambda event handler definition
def lambda_handlerOut(event, context):

    # make sure that something was given - likely unneeded
    if len(event) > 0:  
        success=1
        print("length of event outside for--"+str(len(event)))

        # loop through each record in Records
        for record in event['Records']: 
            print("length of event--"+str(len(event)))

            # take a look at the event structure - just extracting parts
            bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']

            # key is the object name - that is, the file
            key=record['s3']['object']['key']

            print("Bucket--"+bucket)
            print("File that triggered this event--"+key)
```

**EDIT**

As I linked to above, the data in the `event` object looks something like:

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
            "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"mybucket",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
               },
               "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
               "size":1024,
               "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
               "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko",
               "sequencer":"0055AED6DCD90281E5"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, as an example, `bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']` starts by getting  the `s3` record from the data which leaves:

```
"s3":{  
    "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
    "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
    "bucket":{  
        "name":"mybucket",
        "ownerIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
         },
         "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
     },
     "object":{  
         "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
         "size":1024,
         "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
         "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko",
         "sequencer":"0055AED6DCD90281E5"
     }
}
```

From there, it gets the `bucket` stanza:

```
"bucket":{  
    "name":"mybucket",
     "ownerIdentity":{  
         "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
      },
      "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
}
```

and lastly, the `name`:

```
"name":"mybucket"
```

This is assigned to the variable bucket which is printed out later.  The `key` (which is the file name in this example) works the same way but gets different parts of the `event`.

Does that make sense now?

Comment: Could you please explain this code with a sample s3 value?